# Allowing to type in textbox after postback on keydown

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback, onkeydown

I am trying to create a textbox that executes a c# function on keydown, so I ordered a javascript function to postback on keydown event of the textbox, basically, what happened is I had the textbox on autopostback=true and the c# function executed only when clicking outside the box, because of autopostback, so I wanted to reach the same goal, but without clicking outside, only with keydown. here's my code:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function RefreshBox() 
 {
   __doPostBack('<%= SomeTextBox.ClientID%>', '');
 }
```

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="SomeTextBox" runat="server" onkeydown="RefreshQueryBox();" 
   AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="1" 
   ontextchanged="AutoText_TextChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

here's the .cs

```
        protected void AutoText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Some actions here
}
```

problem is, with this code the entire page refreshes on keydown and the user cannot type. Help! :P

Thanks

Comment: OK what you want makes no sense on a web app at all. You will need to use Ajax.net to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that when you cause a post back you essentially are restarting the life cycle. Which means that you data also does not get preserved correctly. I would advise using a web service call with ajax to do your action.

```
function AutoText(){
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '../Services/UpdateService.asmx/AutoText',
  data: '',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
          //use the data.d to get the info passed back from webservice. then 
          add your logic to update your html
  },
  error: function () {
     //catch any bad data
  } 
 });
}
```

your backend method should look like this. Object is whatever your objcet is

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Object GetLatest()
    {
        Object obj= new Object ();

        obj.FirstName = "Dave";
        obj.LastName = "Ward";

 return obj;
}
```

If you're doing validation I would advise jquery/javascript. Although, you run the risk of someone not allowing javascript on their web browser you offload the work on the server side.

Comment: Yes I should've mentioned I can't use Ajax in this instance, basically what I want is the same postback I get from clicking on the page with autopostback, if at all possible.

Comment: I would wrap your textbox in an update panel then. I would then do updatepanel.update() in your codebehind. Also, I would set your updatepanel to UpdateMode="conditional". This way you can still post back but instead of the whole page reloading only your section with the update panel will

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helps a lot, now I changed the event from onkeydown to onkeyup so that it allows me to write, problem is, every time I type it unfocuses from the texbox, I tried document.getElementById("SomeTextBox").focus(); but it still doesn't allow me to write normally,however it does execute the function but not exactly onkeyup but several seconds after I finish typing.

Comment: With and update panel. Once you do the "updatepanel.update()" you need to re register your javascripts. ex:ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.updatePaneLid, this.GetType(), "Show_Font", "showFont();", true); where showFont is a javascript function that sets the focus back on the textbox

Comment: I did just that but it still unfocuses, I wrapped 2 textboxes in the same update panel, maybe that's obstructing? Anyway my javascript function and scripmanager code:

    UpdateAuto.Update();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdateAuto,      this.GetType(), "Show_Font", "FocusTextBox();", true);

   function FocusTextBox() 
   {
       document.getElementById("SomeTextBox").focus();
   }

Comment: Unless both your textboxes have the same id i dont think it would obstruct it. Have you tried to debug/step through your javascript. I have a feeling that your javascript isn't accessing the update panel.

Comment: You're correct it doesn't access it directly, I'm only __doPostBack on the SomeTextBox. What function should I use on the update panel?

Comment: So I looked into it more. It looks like i told you the wrong line of code above. Try this ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "alert('Member Registered Sucessfully');", true). Either pass in the function or explicitly call your js script. IE: document.getElementById("SomeTextBox").focus(). The full code should look like. ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "function focusTxtBox() {document.getElementById("SomeTextBox").focus();}", true)

Comment: Yes that doesn't do the job at all, I suppose you meant instead of this.Page, this.UpdatePanel, anyhow I tried both and I took the "" off the SomeTextBox in the function calling because it disrupts the string structure and it's problematic.

Comment: Hmm....Can you c/p the code snippet where you are doing your update panel.update as well as the section where your update panel is in your aspx. =)

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAuto.Update();
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.UpdateAuto, this.UpdateAuto.GetType(), "script", "function FocusTextBox() {document.getElementById(SomeTextBox).focus();}", true);
    }

Comment: The update panel is too long, it's basically after /div and where the textboxes are, it contains 2 textboxes itself

Comment: Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { UpdateAuto.Update(); ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),"script", "function FocusTextBox() {document.getElementById(\"SomeTextBox\").focus();}", true);

Comment: Hopefully it works. If not then I think i'd be more helpful seeing more of your code base so I could help you debug. its hard to conceptualize why you're getting the errors when your code seems to be correct

Comment: Nope it doesn't do the job, just to be clear here I'm not getting any errors, only thing is when i type it unfocuses from the textbox